# Edição de perguntas com mensagens de erro

Tags: suporte

Recentemente editei essa pergunta:

[Problema na licenca sdk ao rodar projeto cordova](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198261)

Nesse caso a formatação não foi efetuada pelo *AP*, pelo contrário, a mensagem de erro contém os caracteres reconhecidos pelo *markdown*, o *AP* simplesmente copiou e colou.

A edição foi recusada pelo motivo:

> Esta edição não faz a publicação mais fácil de ser lida, mais fácil de ser encontrada, mais precisa ou mais acessível. As mudanças são completamente supérfluas ou de fato prejudicam a legibilidade.

Ao meu entender a *edição faz a publicação mais fácil de ser lida*.

Answer (score 6):

Aparentemente ficaria melhor mesmo, pouco, mas deve melhorar. Faça de novo que eu tento aprovar.